# Gap at top of webpage. no gap showing on dreamweaver

Tags: html

i'm a bit stumped.

on my website its showing a little gap between the header and navigation bar. im not sure why or how to get rid of it.

[www.elite-arcades.com](http://www.elite-arcades.com)

can anyone help out?

heres the code:

```
  <!--new header section ends -->

        <tr>
            <td>
              <img src="layout/eliteheader.jpg" alt="Elite Gaming | The UK's Premier Arcade Machine Supplier" width="900" height="235" />                  </td>
        </tr>


 <!-- Navigation Menu Begins -->

    <tr bordercolor="#000000">
    <td background="layout/background1.gif">
        <div id="Navigation" style="PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 50px; PADDING-RIGHT: 50px; PADDING-TOP: 0px;">
```

and the CSS:

```
body {
color:#333333;
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
text-decoration: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  `vertical-align:top`  to the elite header image like below and the issue will be get resolved.

```
<img style="vertical-align: top" width="900" height="236" alt="Elite Gaming | The UK's Premier Arcade Machine Supplier" src="layout/eliteheader.jpg">
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have `cellspacing` set to `28` in the following line:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="28" width="100%">
```

You need to set it to 0 and check to see that it doesn't have any impact on other parts of the page layout.